# Using a function in a select statement with multiple tables while creating a view

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using oracle SQL developer, the create view tool. I have a function called LastNameFirst that I want to use to reorganize the customers first name / last name to appear with the last name being first.

```
SELECT SALE.SaleID,SALE.SaleDate, CUSTOMER.LastNameFirst(LastName,FirstName), 
SALE_ITEM.SaleItemID,SALE_ITEM.ItemID,ITEM.ItemDescription, ITEM.ItemPrice

FROM SALE_ITEM
INNER JOIN SALE on SALE.SaleID = SALE_ITEM.SaleID
INNER JOIN ITEM on ITEM.ItemID = SALE_ITEM.ItemID
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER on CUSTOMER.CustomerID = SALE.CUSTOMERID;
```

The error i'm getting is :
    ORA-00904: "CUSTOMER"."LASTNAMEFIRST": invalid identifier

How do I call the function in that part of my select statement? I can't seem to find any examples of functions being called in select statements where joins are involved, other than using "cross apply" or "outer apply" in some way. I understand (I think) that the syntax is

```
SELECT 'tableName'.'columnName'
```

and I know my function isn't a column and that's why I'm getting that error. But I'm really not sure of how to set up the code. I tried changing it to something like:

```
SELECT SALE.SaleID,SALE.SaleDate,CUSTOMER.LastName, CUSTOMER.FirstName AS LastNameFirst(LastName,FirstName),SALE_ITEM.SaleItemID,SALE_ITEM.ItemID,ITEM.ItemDescription, ITEM.ItemPrice
```

But nothing like that worked for me either. I'd appreciate any help anyone could give me.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are not properties of tables to be allowed to period qualify them. However, functions and tables among other objects share the same namespace. As mentioned in [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm):

> The following schema objects share one namespace:
>
> - Tables
> - Views
> - Sequences
> - Private synonyms
> - Stand-alone procedures
> - Stand-alone stored functions
> - Packages
> - Materialized views
> - User-defined types

Therefore, simply remove the `CUSTOMER.` qualifier as schema is implicitly defined:

```
SELECT SALE.SaleID, 
       SALE.SaleDate, 
       LastNameFirst(LastName, FirstName) AS Customer_Name, ...
```

Alternatively, explicitly qualify the schema name on all table and function objects in the manner: `"schema"."table"."column"` or `"schema"."function"`:

```
SELECT myschema.SALE.SaleID, 
       myschema.SALE.SaleDate, 
       myschema.LastNameFirst(myschema.CUSTOMER.LastName, 
                              myschema.CUSTOMER.FirstName) AS Customer_Name, ...
```